# Switch to user space

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel

this is part of code which demonstrates basic functions of os kernel. 
After flushing GTD and setting up IDT I want to switch to ring 3 run some int and context switch.
However I cannot jump to user mode. I want to use trick with `iret` instruction. As far I know `iret` will pop
from stack following values: `SS ESP EFLAGS CS EIP` so the idea is push proper values to the stack(with new segment selectors),
and let `iret` set values in registers. Here is the code I am using:

```
    .equ NULL_DESCRIPTOR,  0x0000000000000000

    .equ CODE_P3,          0x40C3FA000000D090 
    .equ DATA_P3,          0x40C3F2000000D090 
    .equ CODE_KERNEL,      0x00CF9A000000FFFF 
    .equ DATA_KERNEL,      0x00CF92000000FFFF 
         GDT:
            .quad NULL_DESCRIPTOR
            .quad CODE_P3       #0x08
            .quad DATA_P3       #0x10
            .quad CODE_KERNEL   #0x18
            .quad DATA_KERNEL   #0x20
        _GDT:
            .word 39
            .long GDT


    .global flushGDT
    .type flushGDT, @function
    flushGDT:
        cli
        lgdt _GDT

        xor %eax, %eax

        #Data segment setup
        mov $0x10, %ax
        mov %ax, %ds
        mov %ax, %gs
        mov %ax, %fs
        mov %ax, %es

        #Stack save
        mov %esp, %eax

        #stack setup for iret and user space return

        pushl $0x10
        pushl %eax

        pushf
        #enable ints after switch to ring 3
        pop %eax
        or $0x200, %eax
        push %eax

        #CS selector
        pushl $0x08
        pushl $0x60 #Address of .leave (I have written proper ld script and checked with objdump)
        iret

    .section .upper_code, "ax", @progbits
    .leave:
        hlt
        call upperKernelCode
```

The problem is with `iret` after starting to execute this instruction check on privilege level of selector and a code is perforem, so in result CPU faults and reset.
Here is log form BOCHS: `check_cs(0x0008): non-conforming code seg descriptor dpl != cpl, dpl=3, cpl=0`. I will much appreciate any help with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bochs told you, your selector `0x08` has `CPL=0` but the descriptor entry has `DPL=3`. Remember that the two least significant bits of the selector are the `CPL`. Thus, to switch to ring3, you should use `0x0b`.

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand. When `iret` is executed, CPU do not check whole entry in GDT? An also, should I use same rule for '%ss', I've changed  `pushl $0x08` to `pushl $0x0b` and I get now `iret: SS.rpl != CS.rpl`

Comment: Yes, same logic. Do you know that CPL is the 2 low bits of the selector?

Comment: Yes, I know that CPL is encoded in two low bits of given selector, but honestly after your answer I do not know how this mechanism work. I thought that CPL(current privilege level) is same as DPL(descriptor privilege level). Honestly now I'm confused how protection level works in CPU. So if I want to write proper privilege level change I should use $0x13 for data and stack?

Comment: Yes, use 0x13. The CPL/RPL/DPL mess is so that you can reuse descriptors for different privilege levels, but nobody does that anyway. So just make sure all of those match.

Comment: Thansk! Just to be clear to get proper value for selector, can I use this formula: `GDT_offset + privlige_level` ?

Comment: Yeah, not much of a formula :) The DPL in the descriptor should match it though.